# How do I log In with GMAIL and get user info (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, gmail

I'm having some trouble getting gmail login to work. In fact, the log in process is already working, but I don't know how to get the user's data (username, email, birthday...). I see there are a lot of APIs to get the calendar, mails, contacts... BUT NOT THE INFO...
I managed to get the contacts (following a tutorial), just expecting to get the data from the response, but it was not there.
The code I have:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("gdata", "1.x");

function setupContactsService() {
    contactsService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0');
}

function logMeIn() {
    var scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';
    var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
}

function btn_login() {
    setupContactsService();
    logMeIn();
}
</script>
```

---

And there is a button that calls btn_login().

I hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: what is scope? How to login to gmail by JavaScript having login and pass? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650773/how-to-silently-log-into-gmail-using-javascript-having-the-login-and-password-gi/25651558#25651558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the source code of this chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gffjhibehnempbkeheiccaincokdjbfe

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I'm reading it, anyway I think there must be an easier way to get that info, given that i've actually managed to log in and retrieve the contacts' info.

Comment: can't get the extension you have mentioned. @seth